# Using random enum to generate objects in java

Tags: java, enums

There are four classes that interact with my project. The aim is to generate an object using enum, using the random values from enum.

1. The `EthicalEngine` class. I'll call the method from another class called `ScenarioGenerator`.
2. The `Person` class inherited from the `Character` abstract class.

I am not sure whether my method of initialization is correct or not. My idea is to initialize the instance of the `Person` in the `ScenarioGenerator` class, and use a method `getRandomPerson()` to call the constructor.

But I stuck, keep getting `NullPointerException` when I called the method.

Here is part of my `Character` class:

```
abstract class Character {

private int age;
private Gender gender;
private BodyType bodyType;
protected Profession profession;
protected AgeCategory ageCategory;
protected boolean isPregnant;

public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN;
}

public enum BodyType {
    AVERAGE, ATHLETIC, OVERWEIGHT, UNSPECIFIED;
}

public enum Profession {
    DOCTOR, CEO, CRIMINAL, HOMELESS, UNEMPLOYED, MUSICIAN, BOXER ,UNKNOWN, NONE;
}

public Character(int age, Profession profession, Gender gender, BodyType bodyType, boolean isPregnant) {
    this.age = age;
    this.profession = profession;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.bodyType = bodyType;
    this.isPregnant = isPregnant;
}
```

part of my `Person` class:

```
Person(int age, Profession profession ,Gender gender, BodyType bodyType, boolean isPregnant) {
    super(age, profession, gender, bodyType, isPregnant);
}
public Profession getProfession () { //use getter to generate a random value
    //only adults have profession
    if (getAge()<=16 || getAge()>68) {
        return Profession.NONE;
    } else {
        return Profession.values()[new Random().nextInt(Profession.values().length)];
    }
//other getters and setters
}
```

Part of my `ScenarioGenerator` class:

public class ScenarioGenerator {

```
private Person person;
private Animal animal;
private Scenario scenario;
private Random random = new Random();

private int passengerCountMinimum;
private int passengerCountMaximum;

private int pedestrianCountMininum;
private int pedestrianCountMaximum;

public ScenarioGenerator() {
    random.setSeed(random.nextInt());
}

public ScenarioGenerator(long seed) {
    this.random = new Random(seed);  
}

public Person getRandomPerson() {
    //need age, gender, bodyType, profession, pregnancy
    Person people = new Person(person.getAge(), person.getProfession(), person.getGender(),person.getBodyType(), person.isPregnant());      
    return people;
}
```

Part of my `EthicalEngine` class:

```
public class EthicalEngine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EthicalEngine ethicalEngine = new EthicalEngine();
    ScenarioGenerator scenarioGenerator = new ScenarioGenerator();
    scenarioGenerator.getRandomPerson();
}
```

Comment: Formulate your question clearer. You're getting NPE when calling which method? can you share also your `ScenarioGenerator` class?

Comment: thank you. I called it when in `EthicalEnglne`, And I only bring out the method `getRandomPerson()` in the `ScenarioGenerator` class. @GiorgiTsiklauri

Comment: ..and you still haven't shared your `ScenarioGenerator` class.

Comment: Thank you. I've already added the class.

Comment: You have a problem into your `ScenarioGenerator` class. Make sure object gets instantiated.. because it is not, and that's why you get NPE.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I'll keep trying. Have a nice day. @GiorgiTsiklauri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate random number and select all values

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ScenarioGenerator {

public Person getRandomPerson() {
    Random rand = new Random();

    // max age
    int age = rand.nextInt(100);

    // no of profession - 1
    int profession = rand.nextInt(8);

    // no of gender - 1
    int gender = rand.nextInt(2);

    // no of bodyType - 1
    int bodyType = rand.nextInt(3);

    int pragnency = rand.nextInt(2);

    //need age, gender, bodyType, profession, pregnancy
    Person people = new Person(age, Profession.values()[profession], Gender.values()[gender],BodyType.values()[bodyType], pragnency == 1 ? true : false);
    return people;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your patience and the answer, appreciate that !